# "Rento departamento": does it mean "Pago" or "cobro por vivir ahí" ? or both?

Tags: verbos

In my oppinion, both forms are correct, but if there is only correct meaning, which is which?

How is called this phenomenon of having a verb, that is the inverse of itself? 
That is,

> Rento un departamento a mi tío.

and

> Mi tío me renta un departamento.

have the same meaning after inverting subject and indirect object.

Comment: Nice question, related to: [How to avoid ambiguity in “I am renting an apartment in New York”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74342/how-to-avoid-ambiguity-in-i-am-renting-an-apartment-in-new-york).

Comment: Ya veo. Preguntaba, porque en Campeche he oido "¿Te presto cien pesos?" (¿mañosamente?) y lo que realmente se pregunta es "¿Me prestas cien pesos?". En Yucatán, "vendo" es sinónimo de "compro", en casos. Raro e interesante, ¿no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This in Spanish is called [enantiosemia](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Enantiosemia) (from greek "enantíos" contrary and "sema" meaning) also called autoantónimo (from the English [autoantonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoantonym)). Both "rentar" and "alquilar" have this property.

> Se llama **enantiosemia** a un tipo de polisemia en el que una palabra
>   tiene dos sentidos opuestos. La oposición entre los significados puede
>   ser de distintos tipos: complementariedad, antonimia graduable,
>   antonimia por reversión o antonimia por conversión [explicar].
>
> A las palabras con enantiosemia también se las llama autoantónimos (en
>   alemán este fenómeno es llamado Gegensinn, y en inglés contronymy).

Comment: +1 Hay que decir que este caso de polisemia (verbos que invierten la dirección sujeto-objeto) es bastante rara.

Answer (score 3):

In **Spain** we do not use the verb `rentar`, but we use `alquilar` with **exactly the same meaning**. About the verb `alquilar`, the [**R.A.E. dictionary**](http://dle.rae.es/alquilar) says:

> #### Alquilar:
>
> 1. **Dar a alguien algo**, especialmente una finca urbana, un animal o un mueble, para que use de ello por el tiempo que se determine y mediante
>      el pago de la cantidad convenida.
> 2. **Tomar de alguien algo** para este fin y con tal condición.

So it can clearly mean **both**. And I think you can apply this to the verb `rentar` in Latin America...

---

That said, and this is just a **personal opinion**, if I heard `"Alquilo apartamento"`, I would think firstly in someone offering a flat to rent. And if I wanted to say that I live in a rented flat I'd say:

> Vivo de alquiler.
>   
>   Tengo un apartamento alquilado.

Comment: +1 Same in Argentina

Comment: "alquilar" is not used in Mexico.

Comment: @AlfredoOsorio, I said that it's so in Spain... anyway I guess you can apply the same explanation to the verb `rentar` in Mexico, can't you?

Comment: @MikO take it easy, just wanted to point out that in Mexico is not used.

Comment: @AlfredoOsorio, yes I understood you only wanted to point that out, actually I just wanted to ask you if you can really apply this to the verb `rentar`, because in fact it's something I'm not sure about... Sorry if I sounded rude or something like that, but not at all ;)

Comment: It's probably true that more people use rentar more often, but to say that alquilar isn't used in Mexico is to tell an out-and-out falsehood.

Answer (score 1):

El fenómeno se llama *enantiosemia*, como [aquí](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3945/rento-departamento-does-it-mean-pago-or-cobro-por-vivir-ahi-or-both/3947#3947) se dijo.

Sinónimos que puedes usar son: alquilar, rentar y arrendar (viene de "arriendo"). En Chile es preferible usar el verbo arrendar por simplementer ser el verbo más usado, y es considerado incorrecto usar el resto por esnobismo/siutiquería.

Comment: I confirm that _arrendar_ is used in Chile.